# How can I temporarily disable delta indexing with Thinking Sphinx?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thinking-sphinx, delta-index

I am running a big migration and would like to disable delta indexing so it runs much faster.

Is there a way to specify in the beginning of the task to turn delta indexing off?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Two options:

```
Model.suspended_delta do
  # all actions in the block don't fire a delta request
end
# A single delta request gets fired at the end
```

Or, what may be better in your situation:

```
ThinkingSphinx.deltas_enabled = false
```

And set it back to `true` when you're done.

Comment: FYI: This is for older versions of ts. See below answer for newer versions.

Answer (score 9):

For thinking sphinx v3, you can suspend the deltas this way (the old way is deprecated):

```
ThinkingSphinx::Deltas.suspend(:index_reference) do
  # Do something
end
```

So if I have a model called Job with an index named :job, it would look like this:

```
ThinkingSphinx::Deltas.suspend(:job) do
  # Do Something
end
```

Comment: And there's also the `ThinkingSphinx::Deltas.suspend!` and `ThinkingSphinx::Deltas.resume!` methods if you want to control things at a finer level - but this won't automatically run delta indexing for any models afterwards.